# Is it Following Some algorithm or formula ..?

Tags: algorithm, math, numbers

Perfect Number series
N:1 =1
N:2 =34 
N:3 =122 
N:4 =1111 
N:5 =11123 
N:6 so on...??

Here N is the number of digits in an Integer.

Number is called perfect if it follow these Rules:-

Number(without leading zeros) does not contain any other zeros. 
The sum of squares of all digits of Number is a perfect square. 

Example:-For N=2 34 
34:- 3^2+4^2 :- 25 which is a perfect square

How to Compute Next smallest N Digit Number of This series is there any algorithm or formula following this series ..??

Comment: Does the number need to be smallesy N digit number ? 
For example for N:2 even 43 is a valid magic number, will that be considered correct

Comment: @RaviChandak sorry my mistake yes it should be smallest. i've Edited the Description

Comment: The term *perfect number* means positive integers equal to the sum of their positive divisors,eg `6 == 1*2*3 == 1+2+3`.  It's just confusing to use the term incorrectly; whatever they are the numbers in the question are not perfect.

Comment: seems to be part of https://oeis.org/A096299

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark that's why i have provided  description of perfect number, which is followed by this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    all := 1
    for all < 21 {
        fmt.Println(keepdo(0,0,all))
        all++
    }

}

func keepdo(i int,sum int, ma int)  (bool, int, string){
    if i>= ma {
        return square_check(sum), sum, ""
    }
    try := 1
    for try < 10 {
        sumc := sum +try*try
        check, s,ss := keepdo(i+1,sumc, ma)
        if check {
            return check, s, strconv.Itoa(try) + ss
        }
        try++
    }
    return false, sum, ""
}

func square_check(a int) bool {
    var int_root int = int(math.Sqrt(float64(a)))
    return (int_root * int_root) == a
}
```

This is a very naive solution.
Should work. Pls do let me know if any improvement

https://play.golang.org/p/drVPaE0R71I

Comment: Ohh mathematically its  doing a dfs
So imagine we try to do all possible values from 1-9 at each position.

So we go from one position to next trying all values from 1-9 and passing along the sum of square

When we reach the last position we do a check to see if the sum is indeed a square of a number.

Once we see that the sum is a square of a certain number we track back and append the values at each index and returning.

We get the lowest value as we go from trying 1 -> 9 for each position.

Comment: @emp1 you dont need to know golang. Its pretty simple to read and can be done in any language

Comment: your recursion would timeout for large values on N.

Comment: The complexity of this algorithm is O(9^N). In that case i have tried ith N= 10000. It gets done in matter of <1 sec

Comment: it time outs for n>= 10^5. Do you have any idea how to optimise it further?

Comment: I am sure there is a way but haven't looked into it.
The approach would be **not** to actually find the value at each position. Instead assume all the values before current position is 1 and try to find a value at current position which helps form a perfect square.
Basically instead of doing dfs from 1st index we do dfs from last index and keep going from last to first to find values.
This is coming from the observation that most of the N digit values generated have a lot of 1s in the start.